# Is it true that Class::Accessor::Fast is only handy for scalar data members?

Tags: perl

It saves our time to write tedious get/set methods.

But it seems to me only handy for scalar data members, won't fit for array/hash data members,right?

Comment: you can always store a _reference_ to an array or hash, and that's a scalar

Answer (score 2):

For most `Class::Accessor` variants, including `Class::Accessor::Fast`, the underlying structure representing the objects are blessed hash references.

Hashes can only store scalars as their values.

However, that doesn't mean you can't store a list of things, a hash of things, or whatever else in your object. Merely take a reference to whatever non-scalar structure you want to store.

All references are scalars, and a hash will be able to store them just fine, no matter if you use direct object access, accessors generated by some `Class::Accessor` variant, `Moose`, or anything else that helps you in building your objects upon hash references.